A problem about $C_0$ semigroup
I'm trying to show the following question:
Suppose $\{T_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is a family of bounded linear operators over a Banach space $X$ satisfying $T_0=I, T_tT_s=T_{t+s}$. And for all $x \in X$, the map
$\varphi_x:t\to T_t(x)$ is a continuous map from $[0,+\infty)$ to $X$. I have showed that there exist two constants $M$ and $\omega$ such that $\|T_t\|\leq Me^{\omega t}$ for all $t\in [0,+\infty)$.
The next problem is to verify that infinitesimal generator $A$ given by $Ax=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{T_tx-x}{t}$ is closed and linear. The latter property is easily checked. For the former one, I have to show that for $\{(x_n,y_n)\}\subset \mathcal{D}(A)$ such that $(x_n,y_n)\to(x_0,y_0),(n\to +\infty)$, there is $Ax_0=y_0$. I wanted to make it with the definition of derivatives. First $x_n\to x_0$ and $y_n=Ax_n \to y_0$ hold. And then by the definition of derivatives, there is :
$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $|t|<\delta,\|\frac{T_tx_n-x_n}{t}-y_n\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then we have the evaluation:
\begin{equation*}
\|\frac{T_{t}x_0-x_0}{t}-y_0\|\leq\|\frac{(T_t-I)(x_0-x_n)}{t}\|+\|\frac{(T_t-I)x_n}{t}-y_n\|+\|y_n-y_0\|
\end{equation*}
By $Ax_n=y_n$ and $y_n\to y_0$, it's clear that as $t\to 0$, the second term can be limited by $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. And the third term can be limited by $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ because $n$ is arbitrary. For the first one, there is :
\begin{equation*}
\|\frac{(T_t-I)(x_0-x_n)}{t}\|\leq\|\frac{T_t-I}{t}\|\|x_n-x_0\|
\end{equation*}
Similar to the third term, $\|x_n-x_0\|\leq\frac{\varepsilon} {3}$ because $n$ is arbitrary. So currently I have to show that $\frac{T_t-I}{t}$ is bounded as $t\to 0$. To make this, I tried to use the conclusion that $\|T_t\|\leq Me^{\omega t}$ to eliminate $t$ but I failed. How can I forge?

This will not help you for the more direct method of proof you are going for, but if you remain stuck one way to proceed is to instead look at $J_\varepsilon(u) := \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_0^\varepsilon T_t(u) \mathrm{d}t$, and show that the $J_\varepsilon$s have some nice commutativity relations with the $t^{-1}(T_t - I)$ both in their images and in their parameters, and also observe that $D(A) \owns J_\varepsilon(u) \to u$ as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ for $u \in X$. It is quite roundabout compared to what you'd like to do currently though, but you get more intel on how the semigroup behaves.
